# Django ошибка - context must be a dict rather than Context

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Версия Django 2.1.2
Изучаю Django и поймал ошибку.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib import messages
from guess.forms import PostForm
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if request.method =='GET':
        return render(request, 'guessApp/index.html', {'name':'Some_name'})

class GuessBook(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = PostForm(request.GET)
        f = RequestContext(request, {'form':form})
        return render_to_response('guessApp/form.html', f)

    def post(self,request):
        form = PostForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, form.cleand_data['message'])
        else:
            message.error(request, 'Validation failed')
        f=RequestContext(request, {'form':form})
        return render_to_response('guessApp/form.html', f )
```

TypeError at /form/
context must be a dict rather than Context.

Comment: Изучаете 2.1.2, а примеры от версии более ранней, чем 1.7. `RequestContext` давно устарел, вместо него используется обычный словарь.

Comment: Честно не знал. Какой в интернете нашел пример, такой и использую. Спасибо, это за помощь. Кстати, может ещё совет дадите? Теперь мне выдает такое:  CSRF cookie not set.

Comment: Лучше используйте официальную документацию. Скорее всего "CSRF cookie not set" выдаёт тоже из-за каких-нибудь несовместимостей.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.